# Additional replication options for large files on IBM Domino

Tags: replication, lotus-domino

Are there any products that can be used with IBM's Domino to handle the replication of large files?  Preferably one that can do byte level replication.  I have an environment(over 50 servers) where large files are placed and changed (bandwidth is a premium). I would like to only replicate the bytes that have changed versus the whole file being replicated over again.   Has anyone used another product to handle byte level changes in files along with the standard Domino replication to handle all the other items?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is anything within Domino or in the Domino space that would do true byte-level replication on file attachments between servers. But, you might want to consider an approach in which you extract / detach attachments from Domino documents to the file system, then use a commercial file-replication product to replicate the files, and use standard Domino replication to replicate the (now much smaller) documents. (In a way, this mimics what DAOS in Notes 8 does, but DAOS is ignorant of replication). It would be simple to create an agent to extract file attachments (and maybe leave a placeholder in the rich-text fields). If you wanted to get fancy, you could replace the attachment with a file icon image inside an action hotspot which has code to launch the appopriate file from the OS. (I'm not sure if all that's needed for that is exposed in the Lotuscript classes, but it's certainly possible from the Notes API).